# how to pass contents of a file line by line to requests module in python

Tags: python, python-requests

I have written this script that will retrieve the contents of a web page.

```
import requests
import bs4

with requests.session() as r:
    r = requests.get("https://www.example.com")
    response = r.text
    print(response)
```

However, I have a list of URLs in a text file. Is there any way I can pass the contents of this file directly to requests.get() instead of typing each one manually.

Comment: use [loops](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put it all in a loop.

```
import requests
import bs4

text_file_name = "list_of_urls.txt"

with requests.session() as session:
    with open(text_file_name) as file:
        for line in file:
            url = line.strip()
            if url:
                resp = session.get(url)
                response = resp.text
                print(response)
```

note: you weren't using the requests session object, so fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a loop

Assuming `file.txt` is your file:

```
with requests.session() as r:
    with open('file.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            r = requests.get(line)
            response = r.text
            print(response)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to loop at all the files and execute a requests.get() for each one

```
import requests
import bs4

with requests.session() as r:
    with open("urls.txt", "r") as f:
        urls = list(f.readlines())
        for url in urls:
            r = requests.get(url)
            response = r.text
            print("Response for " + url)
            print(response)
```

Comment: A bit late to the party, but... you should only create the session object once. That gives requests the opportunity to use a cached http connection. And then use it for the request.

Comment: Fixed, nice tip

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
file1 = open('myfile.txt', 'r')
URLS = file1.readlines()

for url in URLS:
    r = requests.get(url)
    response = r.text
    print(response)
```

This would print the text content of all the URLs